# Bound on partial sums of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, probability-theory

I am trying to prove that for all $\epsilon \gt \frac{1}{2}$, for sufficiently large $n$ it is true that $\sum_{1 \le k \lt \frac{n}{2} - n^e}{n \choose k} \lt \frac{2^n}{n^2}$.  I know the central binomial coefficient is at least $\frac{2^n}{n}$ and I tried working with it a bit by expressing the near-central binomial coefficients in terms of the central one, but got stuck there.  This came up while trying to prove a weaker version of the law of the iterated logarithm.  Hints as well as answers are appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Apply CLT to $P(B(n,1/2)<n/2-n^\epsilon)$

Comment: Okay I can see it is equivalent to $F(\frac{n}{2} - n^e) \lt \frac{1}{n^2}$ where $F$ is the CDF of a binomial distribution $B(n, \frac{1}{2})$, but I'm not sure what to do next or how to use the central limit theorem here.

Comment: I thought CLT ($\frac {B_n-n/2}{\sqrt n/2}\to N(0,1)$) was enough but it isn't. Instead, apply [Bernstein inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_inequalities_(probability_theory)) to $P(\frac{2(B_n-n/2)}{n})<-2n^{\epsilon-1})$ to get $\exp(-\frac{2n^{2\epsilon-1}}{1+2n^{\epsilon-1}/3})$ bound.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) thanks to A.S.'s helpful comments.  Using the notation on that page, the inequality I am trying to prove translates to:

$P(H(n) < \frac{n}{2} - n^\epsilon) \lt \frac{1}{n^2}$

Hoeffding's inequality directly gives the formula:

$P(H(n) < \frac{n}{2} - n^\epsilon) \lt e^{-2 \cdot n^{2 \cdot \epsilon - 1}}$

and since $\epsilon \gt \frac{1}{2}$ we are already done (and this works  with any bound $\frac{1}{n^k}$ not just $\frac{1}{n^2}$).

I would still like to learn how to prove Hoeffding's inequality, I see wiki has a proof but it is for a more general case, if someone can show how to prove just this fact from first principles I will accept that answer.